# Why write() method of OutputStream class doesn't work in the console?

Tags: java, system, outputstream

I'm starting to learn Java and I didn't understand why this code doesn't work:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Principal
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        OutputStream outConsole = System.out;

        outConsole.write(101);
    }
}
```

**System.out** is an **PrintStream** object, **PrintStream** is a subclass of **OutputStream**. **OutputStream** is an abstract class and **write()** is an abstract method of it. So I guess PrintStream must have the write method implemented, why this code doesn't work, then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`PrintStream#write(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#write%28int%29) doesn't automatically flush the stream under all conditions. The javadoc states

> Writes the specified byte to this stream. If the byte is a newline and
>   automatic flushing is enabled then the flush method will be invoked.

In any other case, you need to do so explicitly

```
outConsole.flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

System.out is a PrintSteam, which is [line buffered](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html). Flush it

```
outConsole.flush();
```